# Can I use PowerShell `Expand-Archive` upon a zip file with no extension

Tags: powershell, extract, archive

I'm working upon a PowerShell script, where I have to extract the content out of a `.zip` archive which extension is removed, so, archive's name is let's say not `test.zip` but just `test`, and it is compressed as a `.zip` archive.
I'm trying to use for this purpose the PowerShell cmdlet `Expand-Archive` like shown below :

```
Expand-Archive -LiteralPath "Path to the archive" -DestinationPath "Extraction Path"
```

But, it doesn't seem to work, is there a possibility of extracting this archive's content with powershell, or it would be better to use a work around like 7zip command line tools, or something similar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Expand-Archive` cmdlet is designed to explicitly work with a path that has a `.zip` extension.  You can work around this by either creating a copy of your archive with a proper extension using `Copy-Item` or renaming the archive to have an extension with `Rename-Item` (using `Move-Item` may be more desirable if the archive with extension already exists and you want to overwrite it; `Rename-Item` is not capable of overwriting).