# Open or extract files nupkg with Powershell

Tags: powershell, continuous-integration, teamcity

could you please help me? How I can open and extract files the "nupkg" package using the PowerShell.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Expand-Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive) (you have to rename the file, see [Can I use PowerShell `Expand-Archive` upon a zip file with no extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52725446/can-i-use-powershell-expand-archive-upon-a-zip-file-with-no-extension))

```
Rename-Item "Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.1.nupkg" "Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.1.nupkg.zip"
Expand-Archive "Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.1.nupkg.zip"
```

Comment: Package files are no different than a zip file, you can simply pass that file as-is and it will work the same. `Expand-Archive -Path Newtonsoft.json.12.0.1.nupkg -Destination .`

Comment: You may expand `.nupkg` packages like this with PowerShell Core ( > 5.1), but if you are using Windows PowerShell ( <= 5.1) you still need to rename the `.nupkg` to `.zip` before you expand or you will receive an error ".nupkg is not a supported archive file format.  .zip is the only supported archive file format"

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to use nuget cli, because it also intstalls dependencies. All you need is `nuget install yourpackage` . It's really just a 5MB executable, you can even download it each time you need to get the package:

```
$nugetUrl = "https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $nugetUrl -OutFile ".\nuget.exe" 

.\nuget.exe install yourpackage
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend direct use of `Expand-Archive`. As mentioned by guys at [Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/issues/414) and as you can see in [NuGet sources](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/37d61e55a7e486fba2d224effde3ac7b775f35b8/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Packaging/PackageExtraction/ZipArchiveExtensions.cs#L33) file names in archive are escaped using [URI escaping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.escapedatastring?view=net-6.0).

If you decide to expand raw archive you should afterwards rename all files and directories containing `%` in their names using `Uri.UnescapeDataString`.

If you want more optimised approach in terms of file system writes here's the implementation:

```
function Expand-NugetArchive {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        # File name of the Package
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]
        $FileName,

        # Directory
        [string]
        $ExtractDirectory,

        [boolean]
        $Overwrite = $false
    )

    # Reference to the knowledge here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72590215/3299257
    $extractPath = [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($ExtractDirectory);

    # Ensures that the last character on the extraction path
    # is the directory separator char.
    # Without this, a malicious zip file could try to traverse outside of the expected
    # extraction path.
    if ( -not $extractPath.EndsWith([System.IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString(), [StringComparison]::Ordinal)) {
        $extractPath += [System.IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar;
    }

    $archive = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($FileName)
    try {
        foreach ($entry in $archive.Entries) {
            $fullName = $entry.FullName
            if ($fullName.Contains('%')) {
                $fullName = [Uri]::UnescapeDataString($fullName)
            }

            # Gets the full path to ensure that relative segments are removed.
            $destinationPath = [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath([System.IO.Path]::Combine($extractPath, $fullName))

            [System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($destinationPath)) | Out-Null

            # Ordinal match is safest, case-sensitive volumes can be mounted within volumes that
            # are case-insensitive.
            if ($destinationPath.StartsWith($extractPath, [StringComparison]::Ordinal)) {
                [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::ExtractToFile($entry, $destinationPath, $Overwrite)
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
        if ($null -ne $archive) { $archive.Dispose() }
        throw
    }
}
```